# In a P-N junction, why doesn't charge flow?

Tags: solid-state-physics

I've linked a P-N diagram. My question is why doesn't the positive charge flow with the field and negative charge against the field when there is an electric field pointing from N to P? In equilibrium there is no flow of charge, but in the presence of the electric field, shouldn't there be flow?

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Pn-junction-equilibrium-graphs.png

Comment: Given that the built-in field has brought the carriers into equilibrium, the simple answer is that there is not a driving force to drive carrier flow.

Comment: I don't understand. The net field is non-zero right? It points towards P. There should be a force on the charges.

Comment: And what is the Fermi level doing? It is flat - there is no driving force. You get diffusion but no drift. Yes, a little weird, but not that, considering things like thermocouples and the Seebeck effect.

Comment: Is the point that in equilibrium, the flow of electrons against the field from P to N is negated by electrons moving in the opposing direction from N to P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If carriers enter in the E-field zone they are accelerated by the the field as expected. The issue is that the region is depleted. If a battery is connected in the reverse polarity, there is no electrons in the conduction band of the P-side to go to the other side.

In direct polarity, there are electrons in the conduction band of the N-side to go to the other side. They only need enough tension from the battery to overcome the joint E-field. And the process continues because the battery is a source of carriers to the wires.

The diagram only shows excess of charges in each side. The negative charges in the left side for example came from the conduction zone of N-side and are filling lower energy states at the valence band of the P-side, eliminating available states in that band close to the junction.

In order to a current flows it is necessary available neighboring states, so that the average momentum changes from zero to the current direction. Otherwise the movement is only possible by sparks, where some electron can be ejected from its stable position due to high E-field. But it would damage the material, and is different from a continuous current.

Comment: How exactly is the region depleted? The linked diagram specifically shows electrons and holes in the region of the electric field.

Comment: @user7348 I edited the answer.

Comment: Sorry, my understanding of what's going on is so poor I can't make sense of anything. I'm sure your answer is good, so I'm upvoting you.